# Generate QR code for multiple cryptocurrency addresses

Tags: address, address-generation

I want to generate my own QR code with my main cryptocurrency addresses without using an online solution, is there maybe a command prompt way or particular piece of software I cam download for this, many thanks.

Also please move to correct section if this is in the wrong place

Answer (score 1):

You could use offline JS libraries either with your browser or in your console.

### Command Prompt

*Requires NodeJS & NPM to be installed*

`npm install -g qrcode-terminal`

`qrcode-terminal '1SomeCryptoCurrencyAddressOrPK'`

### Offline in Browser

Or in your browser with an offline library

Save a copy of the raw qrcode.js file to your computer as a javascript file. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs/master/qrcode.js

Then simply use it within an html file

```
<html>
<script src="qrcode.js"></src>
<div id="qrcode"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), "1SomeCryptoCurrencyAddress");
</script>
</html>
```